# SQL Group BY using strings in new columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

I have a database of race results. Each race event has multiple classes.

`events` table:

```
event_id | event_date
---------+------------
1        | 11/5/14
2        | 11/12/14
3        | 11/19/14
```

results table:

```
result_event | name          | class | position
-------------+---------------+-------+-----------
1            | Jason Smith   | 40    | 1
1            | David Johnson | 40    | 2
1            | Randy White   | 30    | 1
1            | Billy Hansen  | 30    | 2 
2            | Wally Mann    | 40    | 1
2            | Shawn Little  | 40    | 2
2            | Eric Davis    | 30    | 1
2            | Tom Handy     | 30    | 2
```

I want to create a summary table that lists the Event Date and the winners of each class.

Like this:

```
Event Date  | Class 40 Winner | Class 30 Winner
------------+-----------------+------------------
11/5/14     | Jason Smith     | Randy White
11/12/14    | Wally Mann      | Eric Davis
```

What query would I need so that I can create a `GROUP BY event_id` and list winners in separate columns?

Comment: *"I've tried and tried,"* - Please show what you've tried. Correcting your attempt may be easier than writing a query from scratch, and it may be more informational for you to learn what exactly you did wrong.

Comment: `GROUP BY` cannot help you here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the `events` table on two queries from the `results` table, one for each class:

```
SELECT    event_data, class_40_winner, class_30_winner
FROM      events e
LEFT JOIN (SELECT result_event, name AS class_40_winner
           FROM   results 
           WHERE  class = 40 AND position = 1) c40 ON e.id = c40.result_event
LEFT JOIN (SELECT result_event, name AS class_30_winner
           FROM   results 
           WHERE  class = 30 AND position = 1) c30 ON e.id = c30.result_event
```

Comment: Yes, this did it.  Thanks!   Is there a functional reason that you give table "events" an alias of "e", or do you do that just to save keystrokes when you need to refer to the table later in the query?

Comment: `events` doesn't really need an alias in this case, it's just shorter to write every time, as you suspected.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ... )` does not optimize well.  See [_follow on_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41647621/mysql-query-taking-over-6-seconds)

Answer (score 0):

You are querying like pivoting data, so I suggest you to use a query like this:

```
select event_date
    , max(case when r.class = 40 then name end) `Class 40 Winner`
    , max(case when r.class = 30 then name end) `Class 30 Winner`
from events e
left join results r on e.event_id = r.result_event and r.position = 1
group by event_date;
```

[[SQL Fiddle Demo]](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0a43/3)