# MySQL Query taking over 6 seconds

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, query-performance

Awhile back I got some help with a specific query. Here's the link: [SQL Group BY using strings in new columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31012881/sql-group-by-using-strings-in-new-columns)

My query looks similar to this:

```
SELECT    event_data, class_40_winner, class_30_winner
FROM      events e
LEFT JOIN (SELECT result_event, name AS class_40_winner
       FROM   results 
       WHERE  class = 40 AND position = 1) c40 ON e.id = c40.result_event
LEFT JOIN (SELECT result_event, name AS class_30_winner
       FROM   results 
       WHERE  class = 30 AND position = 1) c30 ON e.id = c30.result_event
```

I have now entered enough data in my database (22,000 rows) that this query is taking over 6 seconds to complete.  (My actual query is bigger than the above, in that it now has 4 joins in it.)

I used the "Explain" function on my query to take a look.  Each of the queries from the "results" table is pulling in the 22,000 rows, so this seems to be the problem.

I have done some research and it sounds like I should be able to INDEX the relevant column on the "results" table to help speed things up.  But when I did that, it actually slowed my query down to about 10 seconds.

Any suggestions for what I can do to improve this query?

Comment: Don't do subselects - just JOIN

Comment: This solution conflates an issue of data retrieval with an issue with of data display. Handle the display issue in application code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, you are pivoting your data and I think using `max(case ...) ... group by` has good performance in pivoting data.
I can suggest you to use this query instead:

```
select event_date
    , max(case when r.class = 40 then name end) `Class 40 Winner`
    , max(case when r.class = 30 then name end) `Class 30 Winner`
from events e
left join results r on e.event_id = r.result_event and r.position = 1
group by event_date;
```

[[SQL Fiddle Demo]](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0a43/3)

Comment: This one looks like it might work.  What is the "max" function doing in this expression?

Also, if I have another restriction in the query that I want to apply to all the results, would I just add it before the "group by" statement?

Such as: 
.
    where extract(year from e.event_date)='2016'

Comment: The combination of `max` and `case` do the trick, case results will have some `null` values then `max` will discard them  - and you can add any `where` statement before `group by` - HTH ;).

Comment: Hopefully last question.  "name" is actually on a separate table of "entrants". So instead of "name" I have "entrant_id" in the query.  Where do I put the JOIN to join the results.entrant_id field to the entrants.id field?

Comment: Simply add it to query after `from events e` ;).

Comment: I tried that, but it only grabs the name from one of the columns.  SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1135a/2

Comment: Yes!  That's it.  My 6 second query is now down to .029 seconds.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT
  e.event_date,
  r1.name as class_40_winner,
  r2.name as class_30_winner
FROM
  events e,
  results r1,
  results r2
WHERE
  r1.class = 40 AND
  r2.class = 30 AND
  r1.position = 1 AND
  r2.position = 1 AND
  r1.result_event = e.id AND
  r2.result_event = e.id
```

Comment: Thanks.  This seems to get close to what I want.  But if the "40" class is empty for an event, then no row is returned for that event.  I tried changing the "AND" between 40 and 30 to an "OR" but that causes the query to freeze.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.event_data
     , r.class
     , r.name winner
  FROM events e
  JOIN results r
     ON r.result_event = e.id 
 WHERE  class IN (30,40) 
   AND position = 1
```

The rest of this problem is a simple display issue, best resolved in application code.